# Quartz.net + NHibernate + Windsor.Castle + CommonServiceLocator

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-windsor, quartz-scheduler

I have a web application based on the [sharp-architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) framework. It actually use NHibernate for the dal, and i've added a service layer between the (VIEW-CONTROLLER) and the DAL.

I actually need to implement a scheduler to run my jobs frequently. I will use **Quartz.net** to do that task. Actually i'm facing a problem. Because I will have lot's of jobs that will run at different schedule, like every 30 sec, every days, every weeks.

I want to know if there is a way to run **NHibernate** with service injection inside Quartz, and if it will support job concurrence, I mean if two jobs runs **simultaniously**, if there will be no problems with NHibernate. I know there is some issue with NHibernate and **multithreading**.

I found an implementation of Quartz.Net for Spring (http://www.zorched.net/2009/03/07/using-quartznet-springnet-and-nhibernate-to-run-scheduled-tasks-in-aspnet/) and an implementation for Castle-Windsor (http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/03/windsor-facility-for-quartznet.html).

The problem is, I think this examples don't take care of the case that jobs can be ran simultaniously, that's an Nhibernate problem. And i want to use **CommonServiceLocator** to be more high level and not limit myself to one **IoC** framework.

**What can be the best approach to solve this problem ?**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where are you planning to use CommonServiceLocator exactly? I don't see how you would benefit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [NHibernate facility](http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/nhibernate/index.html), then inject `ISessionManager` in your `IJob`s. That should give you one ISession per thread and you should have no problems.

Comment: In my Jobs i use Workflow Foundation to handle in a more readable way the logic. In each Activities I need to access particular services and i use CommonServiceLocator because in one line I get the services : var orderService = (IOrderService)ServiceLocator.Current.GetService(typeof(IOrderService));

Comment: inject the IOrderService (push) instead of asking for it (pull). Remember the Hollywood principle...

Comment: See the workflow facility (http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/Castle.Facilities.WorkflowIntegration) if you need to inject services to your workflow stuff

Comment: K i got it! But i need to inject the repository and a manager to get my Service working. Can i do that by code of i have to make a configuration file. By code I mean a Castle automatic generic injection, so i dun need to specify each repository by hand.

Comment: I'm using the scheme of the Sharp Arch if you need a sample i can provide one

Comment: to register generic components without defining type parameter: http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2008/04/13/windsor-container-registration-of-generic-component-via-c-code.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See this http://docs.castleproject.org/Contrib.Quartz-Net-integration.ashx